# Consider the set $A = \{1, 2, \ldots , n\}$. Count the number of subsets of $A$ of cardinality $k$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the set $A = \{1, 2, \ldots , n\}$. Count the number of subsets of $A$ of cardinality $k$ in two ways. One of those ways must be to count them in two steps as follows.

• How many subsets of cardinality $k$ do not contain the numbers $1$ and $2$?

• How many subsets of cardinality $k$ do contain the numbers $1$ and/or $2$?

I need to count this $2$ ways and I can't figure out the second way that has to do with the bullet points. Can anyone help?

Comment: I assume they are trying to point out the identity $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-2}{k-2}+2\binom{n-2}{k-1}+\binom{n-2}{k}$

Comment: What did you get when you counted them the first way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it into three cases:

1 - contains neither 1 nor 2 $$n_1 = \binom{n-2}k$$
2 - contains a 1 but no 2 $$n_2 = \binom{n-2}{k-1}$$

3 - contains a 2 but no 1 $$n_3= \binom{n-2}{k-1}$$

Comment: Not quite.  You overlooked the case contains both a $1$ and a $2$.